# Finding XML node text and using its ID

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following (example) of my xml document:

```
<Students>
    <Student ID = *GUID NUMBER*>
    <FullName>John Smith</FullName>
    <Address>123 Fake St</Address>
    </Student>
    <Student ID = *GUID NUMBER*>
    <FullName>Henry Doe</FullName>
    <Address>321 Whatever Lane</Address>
```

With  more data in each person. What I want to do is in a c# windows app form, click a button that will search for the 'FullName' field that the user has selected, and get the ID of that user entry, so that I can use that ID to fill a form.
IE: User selects 'John Smith' and presses 'Go'. This will populate the fields of the form with John Smith's data.
So I am thinking of 2 things, using 'SelectSingleNode'? to get the text of the FullName node, and then somehow of getting the users ID?
The rest of my code is using XmlDocument calls.

This is what I have so far:

```
string FullName = StudentSelectStudentComboBox.Text;
XmlDocument fullnamefinderdoc = new XmlDocument();
fullnamefinderdoc.Load("Data.xml");
XmlNode node = fullnamefinderdoc.SelectSingleNode("//[FullName='FullName']");
if (node != null)
{ string studentID = node.Attributes["ID"].Value; }
MessageBox.Show("Student ID is: " + studentID);
```

Comment: This seems to be getting there?

XmlDocument fullnamefinderdoc = new XmlDocument();
            fullnamefinderdoc.Load("Data.xml");
            XmlNode node = fullnamefinderdoc.SelectSingleNode("//FullName");

Comment: `SelectSingleNode("//[FullName='FullName']");` this will search for a student call "FullName"... obviously, you don't have such a student...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
public string FindStudentID(string fullName)
{
   string result = string.Empty;

   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load(@"your-xml-file-name.xml");

   string xpath = string.Format("/Students/Student[FullName='{0}']", fullName);
   XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

   if (node != null)  // we found John Smith
   {
      result = node.Attributes["ID"].Value;
   }

   return result;
}
```

That should find the student node for "fullName", and extract the string representation of the "ID" attribute, which you can then cast to a GUID in C#.

From your code, call is with:

```
private void StudentGoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string myStudentID = FindStudentID(StudentSelectStudentComboBox.Text);
}
```

Marc

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: 
string FullName = StudentSelectStudentComboBox.Text;
            XmlDocument fullnamefinderdoc = new XmlDocument();
            fullnamefinderdoc.Load("Data.xml");
            XmlNode node = fullnamefinderdoc.SelectSingleNode("//[FullName='FullName']");
            if (node != null)
            { string studentID = node.Attributes["ID"].Value; }
            MessageBox.Show(studentID);

Comment: Sorry, where should I put them so they can be formatted correctly?

Comment: I've put them into the original question. :)

Comment: I'm pretty new to C# (if you couldn't tell already!). I have a button called: "StudentGoButton". In my form code:
private void StudentGoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Where do I put your code from above?